# raspberrypi 4 and pulseaudio issue when restarting lightdm

Tags: kodi, pulseaudio, vlc

i been searching for solution for few days but cannot find any.
i have an issue with the pulseaudio.

i have raspberry pi4b(64bit) with kodi installed and vlc running simultaneously.

  -Linux raspberrypi 5.15.61-v8+ #1579 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 26 11:16:44 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

  -TV connected with HDMI1 (kodi will use hdmi TV speaker)

  -speaker connected to AV jack (listening to VLC streaming)

my issue started when

1. sudo service lightdm restart
2. pulseaudio profile for AV jack is missing from sound on taskbar
3. vlc stoped playing sound

i did this because i want to return to desktop after quitting kodi and maybe changing the vlc volume. but since this issue, i had to use guiless vlc using cvlc and the vlc sound no longer stoped.

but everytime i do this the sound output in kodi always reverted back to pulse audio instead of HDMI.

what i tried:

1. pulseaudio -k pulseaudio -D
2. removed /home/pi/.config/pulse

---- or
is there any other best way to start/stop kodi and return back to desktop?

 - i start kodi using kodi-standalone &

 - and stop using kill pid

 - not sure why i cannot use systemctl for this kodi (installed using apt install kodi)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that restarting the lightdm while vlc is still running is the problem.

my solution was to quit the vlc, restart lighdm.

now i can listen to VLC using AV jack, while watching tv using hdmi sound and go back to desktop whenever i need without having to reboot.

tq.